# Getting an error during run make

Tags: c++

I am implementing `RTP protocol` in `NS-2.35`. on the platform `Ubuntu 12.04`. I have made some changes in the existing modules as per required. now I am configuring the changes and run make in the terminal. but getting the following error.

The error is at this step

```
<all the g++ call that cause the error>
```

And the error :

```
common/session-rtp.o: In function hdr_rtp_v2::access(Packet const*)': 
session-rtp.cc:(.text._ZN10hdr_rtp_v26accessEPK6Packet[hdr_rtp_v2::access(Packet const*)]          +0x7): undefined reference to `hdr_rtp_v2::offset_' 
common/session-rtp.o: In function `hdr_rtcp_v2::access(Packet const*)': 
session-rtp.cc:(.text._ZN11hdr_rtcp_v26accessEPK6Packet[hdr_rtcp_v2::access(Packet const*)]  +0x7): undefined reference to `hdr_rtcp_v2::offset_'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

code:

```
#ifndef lint 
static const char rcsid[] = 
    "@(#) $Header: /nfs/jade/vint/CVSROOT/ns-2/apps/rtp.cc,v 1.26 2000/08/18 18:34:01 haoboy Exp $"; 
#endif 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include "agent.h" 
#include "config.h" 
#include "rtp.h" 
#include "random.h" 
#include <string.h> 
#include "rtp_v2.h" 
#include "address.h" 
#include "udp.h" 
#include "ip.h" 
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <iostream.h> 
#include <time.h> 

int hdr_rtp_v2::offset_; 

// RTP RFC 3550 Compliant Header Class 
static class RTP_v2HeaderClass : public PacketHeaderClass { 
public: 
    RTP_v2HeaderClass() : PacketHeaderClass("PacketHeader/RTP_v2", sizeof(hdr_rtp_v2)) { 
        bind_offset(&hdr_rtp_v2::offset_); 
    } 
} class_rtp_v2_hdr; 
// [...]
```

:

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include "agent.h" 
#include "config.h" 
#include "rtp.h" 
#include "random.h" 
#include <string.h> 
#include "rtcp_v2.h" 
#include "address.h" 
#include "udp.h" 
#include "rtp_v2.h" 

#define Receiver_Report 201 
#define Sender_Report 200 
#define seqno_initial_ 0 


class RTCP_v2Agent; 
int hdr_rtcp_v2::offset_; 
// [...]



g++ -Wl,-export-dynamic  -o ns tcp/linux/tcp_naivereno.o tcp/linux/src/tcp_cong.o tcp/linux/src/tcp_highspeed.o tcp/linux/src/tcp_bic.o tcp/linux/src/tcp_htcp.o tcp/linux/src/tcp_scalable.o tcp/linux/src/tcp_cubic.o tcp/linux/src/tcp_westwood.o tcp/linux/src/tcp_vegas.o tcp/linux/src/tcp_hybla.o tcp/linux/src/tcp_illinois.o tcp/linux/src/tcp_yeah.o tcp/linux/src/tcp_veno.o tcp/linux/src/tcp_compound.o tcp/linux/src/tcp_lp.o tcp/linux/ns-linux-c.o tcp/linux/ns-linux-param.o tools/random.o tools/rng.o tools/ranvar.o common/misc.o common/timer-handler.o common/scheduler.o common/object.o common/packet.o common/ip.o routing/route.o common/connector.o common/ttl.o trace/trace.o trace/trace-ip.o classifier/classifier.o classifier/classifier-addr.o classifier/classifier-hash.o classifier/classifier-virtual.o classifier/classifier-mcast.o classifier/classifier-bst.o classifier/classifier-mpath.o mcast/replicator.o classifier/classifier-mac.o classifier/classifier-qs.o classifier/classifier-port.o src_rtg/classifier-sr.o src_rtg/sragent.o src_rtg/hdr_src.o adc/ump.o qs/qsagent.o qs/hdr_qs.o apps/app.o apps/telnet.o tcp/tcplib-telnet.o tools/trafgen.o trace/traffictrace.o tools/pareto.o tools/expoo.o tools/cbr_traffic.o adc/tbf.o adc/resv.o adc/sa.o tcp/saack.o tools/measuremod.o adc/estimator.o adc/adc.o adc/ms-adc.o adc/timewindow-est.o adc/acto-adc.o adc/pointsample-est.o adc/salink.o adc/actp-adc.o adc/hb-adc.o adc/expavg-est.o adc/param-adc.o adc/null-estimator.o adc/adaptive-receiver.o apps/vatrcvr.o adc/consrcvr.o common/agent.o common/message.o apps/udp.o common/session-rtp.o apps/rtp.o tcp/rtcp.o common/ivs.o common/messpass.o common/tp.o common/tpm.o apps/worm.o tcp/tcp.o tcp/tcp-sink.o tcp/tcp-reno.o tcp/tcp-newreno.o tcp/tcp-vegas.o tcp/tcp-rbp.o tcp/tcp-full.o tcp/rq.o baytcp/tcp-full-bay.o baytcp/ftpc.o baytcp/ftps.o tcp/scoreboard.o tcp/scoreboard-rq.o tcp/tcp-sack1.o tcp/tcp-fack.o tcp/scoreboard1.o tcp/tcp-linux.o tcp/linux/ns-linux-util.o tcp/tcp-asym.o tcp/tcp-asym-sink.o tcp/tcp-fs.o tcp/tcp-asym-fs.o tcp/tcp-int.o tcp/chost.o tcp/tcp-session.o tcp/nilist.o sctp/sctp.o apps/sctp_app1.o sctp/sctp-timestamp.o sctp/sctp-hbAfterRto.o sctp/sctp-multipleFastRtx.o sctp/sctp-mfrHbAfterRto.o sctp/sctp-mfrTimestamp.o sctp/sctp-cmt.o sctp/sctpDebug.o dccp/dccp_sb.o dccp/dccp_opt.o dccp/dccp_ackv.o dccp/dccp_packets.o dccp/dccp.o dccp/dccp_tcplike.o dccp/dccp_tfrc.o tools/integrator.o tools/queue-monitor.o tools/flowmon.o tools/loss-monitor.o queue/queue.o queue/drop-tail.o adc/simple-intserv-sched.o queue/red.o queue/semantic-packetqueue.o queue/semantic-red.o tcp/ack-recons.o queue/sfq.o queue/fq.o queue/drr.o queue/srr.o queue/cbq.o queue/jobs.o queue/marker.o queue/demarker.o link/hackloss.o queue/errmodel.o queue/fec.o link/delay.o tcp/snoop.o gaf/gaf.o link/dynalink.o routing/rtProtoDV.o common/net-interface.o mcast/ctrMcast.o mcast/mcast_ctrl.o mcast/srm.o common/sessionhelper.o queue/delaymodel.o mcast/srm-ssm.o mcast/srm-topo.o routing/alloc-address.o routing/address.o lib/int.Vec.o lib/int.RVec.o lib/dmalloc_support.o webcache/http.o webcache/tcp-simple.o webcache/pagepool.o webcache/inval-agent.o webcache/tcpapp.o webcache/http-aux.o webcache/mcache.o webcache/webtraf.o webcache/webserver.o webcache/logweb.o empweb/empweb.o empweb/empftp.o realaudio/realaudio.o mac/lanRouter.o classifier/filter.o common/pkt-counter.o common/Decapsulator.o common/Encapsulator.o common/encap.o mac/channel.o mac/mac.o mac/ll.o mac/mac-802_11.o mac/mac-802_11Ext.o mac/mac-802_3.o mac/mac-tdma.o mac/smac.o mobile/mip.o mobile/mip-reg.o mobile/gridkeeper.o mobile/propagation.o mobile/tworayground.o mobile/nakagami.o mobile/antenna.o mobile/omni-antenna.o mobile/shadowing.o mobile/shadowing-vis.o mobile/dumb-agent.o common/bi-connector.o common/node.o common/mobilenode.o mac/arp.o mobile/god.o mobile/dem.o mobile/topography.o mobile/modulation.o queue/priqueue.o queue/dsr-priqueue.o mac/phy.o mac/wired-phy.o mac/wireless-phy.o mac/wireless-phyExt.o mac/mac-timers.o trace/cmu-trace.o mac/varp.o mac/mac-simple.o satellite/sat-hdlc.o dsdv/dsdv.o dsdv/rtable.o queue/rtqueue.o routing/rttable.o imep/imep.o imep/dest_queue.o imep/imep_api.o imep/imep_rt.o imep/rxmit_queue.o imep/imep_timers.o imep/imep_util.o imep/imep_io.o tora/tora.o tora/tora_api.o tora/tora_dest.o tora/tora_io.o tora/tora_logs.o tora/tora_neighbor.o dsr/dsragent.o dsr/hdr_sr.o dsr/mobicache.o dsr/path.o dsr/requesttable.o dsr/routecache.o dsr/add_sr.o dsr/dsr_proto.o dsr/flowstruct.o dsr/linkcache.o dsr/simplecache.o dsr/sr_forwarder.o aodv/aodv_logs.o aodv/aodv.o aodv/aodv_rtable.o aodv/aodv_rqueue.o aomdv/aomdv_logs.o aomdv/aomdv.o aomdv/aomdv_rtable.o aomdv/aomdv_rqueue.o puma/puma.o mdart/mdart_adp.o mdart/mdart_dht.o mdart/mdart_ndp.o mdart/mdart_neighbor.o mdart/mdart_queue.o mdart/mdart_table.o mdart/mdart.o common/ns-process.o satellite/satgeometry.o satellite/sathandoff.o satellite/satlink.o satellite/satnode.o satellite/satposition.o satellite/satroute.o satellite/sattrace.o rap/raplist.o rap/rap.o rap/media-app.o rap/utilities.o common/fsm.o tcp/tcp-abs.o diffusion/diffusion.o diffusion/diff_rate.o diffusion/diff_prob.o diffusion/diff_sink.o diffusion/flooding.o diffusion/omni_mcast.o diffusion/hash_table.o diffusion/routing_table.o diffusion/iflist.o tcp/tfrc.o tcp/tfrc-sink.o mobile/energy-model.o apps/ping.o tcp/tcp-rfc793edu.o queue/rio.o queue/semantic-rio.o tcp/tcp-sack-rh.o tcp/scoreboard-rh.o plm/loss-monitor-plm.o plm/cbr-traffic-PP.o linkstate/hdr-ls.o mpls/classifier-addr-mpls.o mpls/ldp.o mpls/mpls-module.o routing/rtmodule.o classifier/classifier-hier.o routing/addr-params.o nix/hdr_nv.o nix/classifier-nix.o nix/nixnode.o routealgo/rnode.o routealgo/bfs.o routealgo/rbitmap.o routealgo/rlookup.o routealgo/routealgo.o nix/nixvec.o nix/nixroute.o diffserv/dsred.o diffserv/dsredq.o diffserv/dsEdge.o diffserv/dsCore.o diffserv/dsPolicy.o diffserv/ew.o diffserv/dewp.o queue/red-pd.o queue/pi.o queue/vq.o queue/rem.o queue/gk.o pushback/rate-limit.o pushback/rate-limit-strategy.o pushback/ident-tree.o pushback/agg-spec.o pushback/logging-data-struct.o pushback/rate-estimator.o pushback/pushback-queue.o pushback/pushback.o common/parentnode.o trace/basetrace.o common/simulator.o asim/asim.o common/scheduler-map.o common/splay-scheduler.o linkstate/ls.o linkstate/rtProtoLS.o pgm/classifier-pgm.o pgm/pgm-agent.o pgm/pgm-sender.o pgm/pgm-receiver.o mcast/rcvbuf.o mcast/classifier-lms.o mcast/lms-agent.o mcast/lms-receiver.o mcast/lms-sender.o queue/delayer.o xcp/xcpq.o xcp/xcp.o xcp/xcp-end-sys.o wpan/p802_15_4csmaca.o wpan/p802_15_4fail.o wpan/p802_15_4hlist.o wpan/p802_15_4mac.o wpan/p802_15_4nam.o wpan/p802_15_4phy.o wpan/p802_15_4sscs.o wpan/p802_15_4timer.o wpan/p802_15_4trace.o wpan/p802_15_4transac.o apps/pbc.o diffusion3/lib/nr/nr.o diffusion3/lib/dr.o diffusion3/filters/diffusion/one_phase_pull.o diffusion3/filters/diffusion/two_phase_pull.o diffusion3/lib/diffapp.o diffusion3/ns/diffagent.o diffusion3/ns/diffrtg.o diffusion3/ns/difftimer.o diffusion3/filter_core/filter_core.o diffusion3/filter_core/iolog.o diffusion3/filter_core/iostats.o diffusion3/lib/main/attrs.o diffusion3/lib/main/events.o diffusion3/lib/main/iodev.o diffusion3/lib/main/iohook.o diffusion3/lib/main/timers.o diffusion3/lib/main/message.o diffusion3/lib/main/tools.o diffusion3/apps/gear_examples/gear_common.o diffusion3/apps/gear_examples/gear_receiver.o diffusion3/apps/gear_examples/gear_sender.o diffusion3/apps/rmst_examples/rmst_sink.o diffusion3/apps/rmst_examples/rmst_source.o diffusion3/apps/ping/1pp_ping_sender.o diffusion3/apps/ping/1pp_ping_receiver.o diffusion3/apps/ping/2pp_ping_sender.o diffusion3/apps/ping/2pp_ping_receiver.o diffusion3/apps/ping/ping_common.o diffusion3/apps/ping/push_receiver.o diffusion3/apps/ping/push_sender.o diffusion3/filters/gear/gear_attr.o diffusion3/filters/gear/gear.o diffusion3/filters/gear/gear_tools.o diffusion3/filters/misc/log.o diffusion3/filters/misc/srcrt.o diffusion3/filters/misc/tag.o diffusion3/filters/rmst/rmst.o diffusion3/filters/rmst/rmst_filter.o delaybox/delaybox.o packmime/packmime_HTTP.o packmime/packmime_HTTP_rng.o packmime/packmime_OL.o packmime/packmime_OL_ranvar.o packmime/packmime_ranvar.o tmix/tmix.o tmix/tmixAgent.o tmix/tmix_delaybox.o gen/version.o gen/ns_tcl.o gen/ptypes.o common/win32.o common/tclAppInit.o common/main-monolithic.o -L/home/bhavana/ns-allinone-2.35/tclcl-1.20 -ltclcl -L/home/bhavana/ns-allinone-2.35/otcl -lotcl -L/home/bhavana/ns-allinone-2.35/lib -ltk8.5 -L/home/bhavana/ns-allinone-2.35/lib -ltcl8.5 -lXext -lX11 -lnsl -ldl -lm -lm
```

Can any one suggest what exact modification I have to do with the code in order to resolve the error

if anybody can help me to sort out this... It will be very helpful.
thank you.

Comment: Can you post a list of libraries (with links if applicable) you are using? The last line, `ld returned 1 exit status` means the problem was found in the linking stage and the linker cannot find the function(s) referenced.

Comment: added the codes along with libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

link problem : ld can't find a definition of hdr_rtp_v2::access::Packet(Packet const*) and  hdr_rtcp_v2::access::Packet(Packet const*), Constructors of Packet I guess.

This means you have not defined these functions

Or you forgot to link a lib

Or you are trying to link with ld a lib built with VC which use another name mangling causing this problem

Comment: I have added codes. can you tell me what should I change in the codes?

Comment: can you show the command that `make` executse just before the error ?
...You have declared `int hdr_rtp_v2::offset_` so the first error ie weird, but I don't see `int hdr_rtcp_v2::offset_`

Comment: L/home/bhavana/ns-allinone-2.35/otcl -lotcl -L/home/bhavana/ns-allinone-2.35/lib -ltk8.5 -L/home/bhavana/ns-allinone-2.35/lib -ltcl8.5 -lXext -lX11 -lnsl -ldl -lm -lm         these are the lines before getting error.

Comment: whole command is too long.Not enough space to enter. can you suggest any other way...

Comment: I have added the command before error in the post . Please suggest as early as possible.

Comment: hum... there is only these possibilities : the object files generated from the files where you defined your glob variables are not in the command, or there is an enclosing namespace, or the variable is not declared like you wrote but have everywhere the "extern" qualifier (not probable : seems to be a static var), which is not a definition. Try to look in the .o file generated by the file containing `int hdr_rtp_v2::offset_;`, it should contain `_ZN10hdr_rtp_v27offset_E`

Comment: Or... yet less probable, another compiler with another name mangling was used to generate the .o :D